# Make MVC sitemap send only relevant nodes to visibility provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, mvcsitemapprovider

I have started using MVC sitemap provider a few days ago.
My main objective is to create 2 menus (main menu and side menu), and foreach of those menus iterate over their nodes and to toggle visibility according to a certain business logic.

I have used [this](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#creating-a-custom-sitemapnodevisibilityprovider) article in order to use my own visibility logic.

My layout page contains these lines:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "MainMenu" })
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "SideMenu" })
```

In the current situation every one of these two lines iterates over all of the nodes specified in the **Mvc.sitemap** and i need to first check if they belong to the main or side menu and then continue with my logic.
I would assume there is a way to divide the node between these two menus and skip the part of checking if the menu name from which the node has been sent from.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No concept of "named HTML helpers" exists outside of the `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider`. If you make a custom provider, you will need to check which menu you are in ([just like in `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider.cs#L41)) before running your custom logic.

But that doesn't mean you can't organize the code within the visibility provider into separate pieces.

Comment: Of course i organized my code in my ***IsVisible*** method.
First i check the name of which the node was generated from, and only then invoke my visibility logic.

But this sounds weird, if there is an option to create multiple menus in the layout file that each of them describes different menus, why isn't there a way to route every menu instance to other nodes in the mvc.sitemap file?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "route every menu instance to other nodes"? Every menu is just a different view of the same SiteMap. Do note that if you are using different menu HTML helper templates, you do not necessarily need to use visibility providers since you can put your visibility logic directly in each template. In that case you would specify `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("MainMenu")` in the case where you have a menu template file at `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MainMenu.cshtml`.

Comment: The scenario is that i'm creating a website that will be for internal user in my company.
It will include a top menu that on a certain link click will open a left side menu with the relevant menu items.
The visibility issue is that both the main and side menu will show/hide items according to the current authenticated user.

I know how the implement the visibility part, but not sure how to divide those two menus, actually i want each one to be linked with another sitemap.
Also the side menu is dynamic and should contain items according to the current main menu selection.

Comment: In that case, you should be using [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming), which automatically controls visibility of nodes based on `AuthorizeAttribute`. This will ensure that your node is not just invisible, but the URLs are also not accessible to the user (because `AuthorizeAttribute` will block them).

Comment: Note that you can use security trimming at the same time as visibility. So, you can use the `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` to show/hide each node in the main menu and side menu, and use security trimming to hide those nodes the current user doesn't have access to.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i used security trimming and added authorize attribute, and it works as expected.